# How to share User Database between Two Multisite Installations + More

Tags: multisite, database, users

My situation is a bit different to the other questions/answers I have read online here.

Currently I have a Wordpress Multisite Installation on *Server A*.
Server A is almost full in terms of Storage/Ram & Connections meaning that an upgrade is out of the question.

I have another server, different IP, different host that I would like to install a new Wordpress Multisite installation (Server B).

I would like for the Users from Server A to mirror or be accessible on Server B to allow the users to interact seamlessly. Also Server A has a General Forum where installing another forum on Server B would be pointless if they are the same Topics etc.

Has anyone had experience with this before? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would suggest a server specifically for the database - a DB server. Server A & B could interact with it, and chances are, it would ease some of the tension and performance related issues with Server A.

Comment: Hi Courtney, that is a great suggestion. Never thought of that.

Do you have anymore information regarding about this or how to do this? Tried to do a quick search online but they are all scattered and not many resources on Wordpress.

Thanks

Comment: @lilap - No worries at all! Depending on who you host with, you could add an additional cloud server, and let the host know that you'd like to use it primarily for a large write-heavy MySQL DB. Some hosts offer managed server backups and incremental DB backups as well.